# Call each available queue members just once and then leave the queue in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, queue

I'm using Asterisk 13.30.0 in realtime.

I have a queue and this queue's ring strategy is fewestcalls. I want each call in the queue call the available members in queue just once and then leave the queue.
I tried to autopause and leavewhenempty options together but I couldn't unpause to autopaused members.

Hope, someone has some idea on the matter. How can I do this?

Comment: try https://community.asterisk.org/

Comment: Yes, I tried. but my topic is still pending in there. I thought maybe someone in here knows something about this issue and give me some perspective.

Comment: It is possible via custom state and hints. But even with that it will require external manager for leave it. Anyway what are you asking is pro-level dialplan and will take hours for advanced person to make. So not think someone will write it for free/spend that time for free

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for reply.